# group by/ aggregate in sql presto athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table which looks like so:

```
id, author
1, {entries..}
1, {entries2..}
1, {entries3..}
2, {entry x}
2, {entry y}
</snip>
```

I would like to group by and produce another table which looks like so:

```
id, author
1, [{entries..},{entries2..},{entries3..}]
2, [{entry x},{entry y}]
</snip>
```

ie I want to group by ID and store all the results in an array table in athena/presto.

Comment: As I wrote in our discussion on Saturday - `array_agg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the aggregate function [`array_agg()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.284/functions/aggregate.html#general-aggregate-functions) to return an array created from a specific column :

```
SELECT id,array_agg(author) as author
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```

The Insert can be :

```
INSERT INTO anotherTable
SELECT id, array_agg(author) as author
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: does array_agg() work even if rows are null? ie empty?

Comment: Can't check it now, But If it is like postgresql then ii will work https://dbfiddle.uk/MN_5oHf1

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `GROUP_CONCAT` is used to concatenate the distinct authors into a comma-separated list for each id.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT author) as author
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```